# If $n > 1$ and all $n$ positive integers $a, a + k, \cdots , a+ (n - 1)k$ are odd primes, show every prime $<n \mid k$.

Tags: number-theory

Background: This is from Rosen 5th edition, $3.2.15$ Number Theory.
This is an important proof because $3$ following problems require it to be correct.

[image]

If $i=0$, and $j=p$ then this proof is wrong and $p\mid (i-j)$ and $p$ may not divide $k$. Can this proof be modified so that it is correct or do I not understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $p\nmid k$ for some prime $p<n.$ Then $kx\equiv-a\pmod p$ for some integer $0\leqslant x<p$ so $a+kx\equiv0\pmod p$ and since each of the numbers $a+ik,$ with $0\leqslant i<n,$ is a prime then $a+kx=p.$ Now notice that for each $1\leqslant i<n$ we have $\gcd(a,i)=1$ for otherwise the number $a+ik=\gcd(a,i)\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,i)}+\frac{i}{\gcd(a,i)}k\right)$ would not be a prime. Thus $a\geqslant n.$ Therefore we have $n\leqslant a\leqslant a+kx=p<n,$ which is a contradiction. Thus the primorial $(n-1)\#$ divides $k.$

Comment: This is a great answer! I wish I could up vote for the people that didn't read or understand it.

Answer (score -2):

If $i=0$, then $p$ would have to be equal to $-j$. This would be a contradiction since $i, j, p > 0$. WLOG, we can assume $i-j>0$.

Moreover, since $i \le p$ and $j \le p$, then the claim that $i-j < p$ holds, and the proof is true. Does that help?

Comment: Why would p have to equal -j?

Comment: Everything here is wrong. If $i=0$ we don't have $p=-j.$ Also, "$i,j,p>0$" is not necessarily true because $i$ or $j$ could be $0.$ Also, it is true that $i,j\leqslant p,$ however this doesn't implie that $i-j<p.$